# Prevent QGraphicsItem::itemAt() On a "Background Item"

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set up a GUI using plugins.  In my current phase I need the user to click and specify locations of points.

The plugin architecture I have setup requires the plugin to return QGraphicsItem that the plugin wishes to use.  In the main program (which future plugin writers won't have access to), I set a background image to guide clicks.  The plugins can sneakily access the scene() using an itemChange() and installing an eventFilter() on the scene being set.  This allows for the plugins to have access to scene clicks and process whatever information it needs.  However, the background picture is being returned by itemAt() calls.

I wish to prevent this background Pixmap from returning with an itemAt() for all future plugins.  Is this possible?

---

Tried:

```
 setEnabled(false); //No success
```

Comment: Can you simply reimplement `QGraphicsScene::drawBackground` and draw the pixmap there? Thus no need for an item.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I will definitely look into this.  If you make an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but it should solve your problem: I suggest reimplementing `QGraphicsScene::drawBackground()` and drawing your pixmap there. That's what the method is for.

A similar approach would be to put the pixmap in a resources file, then use style sheets to set it as the background of either the QGraphicsView or its viewport widget (I think these have slightly different effects).

Answer (score 0):

To make an item invisible to itemAt() (or any of the other collision detection methods) you can make the boundingRect() method return a QRectF with zero width and height.

This though has the side effect of making any of the partial viewport update modes of QGraphicsView malfunction, because QGV doesn't have any idea where the item is going to paint itself. This can be remedied by having QGV do full updates on every repaint (setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate)). Depending on your scene this might be an acceptable compromise. If you're using the OpenGL graphics backend the viewport updates will always be full updates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After so many years, here is the answer.
Make your own subclass of `QGraphicsItem` and override the `shape()` method

```
QPainterPath shape() const override
{
    return {};
}
```

Ref to docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#shape

> The shape is used for many things, including collision detection, hit tests, and for the QGraphicsScene::items() functions.

So this will effectively make the item invisible for `itemAt()` and others.
And you still have the `boundingRect()` which is used to filter what items should be painted.